# Name for using different denominator depending on the result in nominator

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Is there a scientific term of using different denominator depending on the result in the nominator where nominator is a diffrence between two variables and denominator is either one of those two variables like in the example:

If (variable1 - variable2) < 0 then **equation** = (variable1 - variable2) / variable2 
Else **equation** = (variable1 - variable2) / variable2

This way the result is a value between -100% and 100%.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your `if` and `else` statements give the same expression?

Comment: something is missing in you description…

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a specific term exists for the operation you are looking for. However, it seems to me that you can reduce your formula to a much simpler one:

$f(x,y) = \frac{x-y}{x*H(x-y)+y*[1-H(x-y)]}$

$H(x-y) = 
\begin{cases}
1 \qquad if \qquad x-y>0 \newline
0 \qquad if \qquad x-y<0
\end{cases}$

In this way, your term $H(x-y)$ can take as value either 0 or 1 (if you include the case $x=y$ in one of the two cases), therefore the denominator becomes either $x$ or $y$, depending on the final equation you are looking for. $H$ is usually called [Heavyside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) (or step function) when you work with time series.

I am sorry but from the format of your question I cannot understand if you need $\frac{(x-y)}{y}$ when $x-y>0$ or the opposite.